# Add or subtract a small fraction of time from system time

Tags: c++, windows, time

Environment: Windows, C++, Visual Studio 2015

I'm trying to do some small scale adjustment to the system time based on a time synchronization algorithm, which returns the time difference between systems in "x seconds, y nanoseconds" format.

I'm aware that Windows offers [SetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx) to adjust system time, but 1) the [SYSTEMTIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx) struct is only accurate to milliseconds, and 2) from my understanding I need to do a get-modify-set routine to count in the time difference, which could affect the accuracy of the action.

Is there a way to adjust system time accurate to microseconds or nanoseconds? Ideally without using external libraries, but I'm still open to those, since it's a practice project with few constraints.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont try to mess with system clock in any way.

I would just wrap this logic in a function which gets time, applies the adjustment and returns the adjusted time. Depends on your adjustment logic, but generally this should not hit performance in any noticeable way.

This allows you both to get adjusted time explicitly if you need, and get raw time otherwise.

Comment: Why does Windows still offer SetSystemTime, though? The alternate implementation does sound reasonable, I'll see if it achieves a consistent result.

Comment: @AndyYan I think Windows offers this just because if it were not you would not be able to change system time at all :) Really wierd situation, even for Windows... Look, this function requires elevated privileges, this is always done for a reason.

Comment: Implementation is quite successful and straightforward - accepted. Thanks!